# converting string array into a key value pair object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting an output which looks like this

```
var x = ["title: x_one", " description: 1", " value: 4"]
```

where `x[0]` returns `title: x_one`

Which is a string. I cant read the property of title. How would I convert it into an object so that eventually I will be able to loop through the array and read the properties such as title, description and value.

I am trying to do this through jquery

I have been looking for a solution but havent really found one. If there is any out there which I am missing I would highly appreciate if anyone else have and could point me to that

Comment: Where are you getting the output from? It looks like it is supposed to be JSON but it is not formatted properly.

Comment: Use `split(':')` to split the value into a property name and value.

Comment: well I am getting the output from our friend google
https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1hAJKYmNsDym6DIQkhZAH8PBtMYndzu9yCLZ1bp_VKCo/od6/public/basic?gid=0&single=true&hl=en_US&alt=json

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Loop through your array, splitting the values at the `:` character. Then use the first part as a property name, the second part as the value, in an object.

```
var obj = {};
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    var split = x[i].split(':');
    obj[split[0].trim()] = split[1].trim();
}
```

Comment: Thanks man..you have answered few of my questions in the past and those were right on :-). Thanks for all your help and helping understanding the concepts

Answer (score 2):

Try this function I have already tested it

```
 var a=new Array();
    for(var i=0;i<x.length;i++){
    var tmp=x[i].split(":")
    a[tmp[0]]=tmp[1]
    }
```

Comment: Except for your inappropriate use of `new Array()`, that's identical to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

A more up to date version that that uses some newer language

```
const splitStr = (x) => {
  const y = x.split(':');
  return {[y[0].trim()]: y[1].trim()};      
}

const objects = ["title: x_one", " description: 1", " value: 4"].map(splitStr)

console.log(objects)
```

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions
- http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object-initializer

Comment: Good use of Lambda (MOZ - Array Functions) functionality.  Although newbies & some mid-levels may mis-use without good knowledge and experience from other languages for its Pro's & Con's, even for JS/JQ

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have an object before you create this array you don't need to convert this to anything. Using jQuery's each you can get the value and the key.

```
$.each( obj, function( key, value ) {
  alert( key + ": " + value );
});
```

If this is the final output then you can just use String.prototype.split when you loop through.

Comment: It's an array, not an object. The keys will just be array indexes `0`, `1`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Just bumped into this. Here is another solution for OP's original array.

```
var x = ["title: x_one", " description: 1", " value: 4"] 


function mapper(str)
{
    var o = {};
    strArr = str.split(":");
    o[strArr[0].trim()] = strArr[1].trim();
    return o;
}


var resultArray = x.map(mapper);
console.log(resultArray[0].title);
console.log(resultArray[1].description);
console.log(resultArray[2].value);
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p1yyeypc/)